# How can I get the GNU screen command to automatically start with every BusyBox ash session?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, busybox

On an embedded device with BusyBox installed I want to set it up so that the gnu screen command is automatically started when any BusyBox session is started.

I have seen that I can add the screen command into the `/etc/profile` file but are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: How do you start your session?

Comment: Via ssh to the device.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ssh you can just have it run instead of the shell (the default) when you connect.

```
ssh -t me@host screen -RD
```

That will create a new session of one does not exist, or otherwise connect to an existing session.

The `-t` flag to ssh tells to to create a pty even though it is not starting a shell. You need that for interactive use.

Answer (score 1):

Add `exec screen -R` at the end of `~/.profile` on the device: every time you log in, your session will reattach the last-created screen session. More precisely, to avoid launching `screen` in non-interactive sessions where you want to read your `.profile` to set environment variables, use this:

```
case $- in *i*) exec screen -R;; esac
```

You will still be able to avoid attaching to screen in an interactive session by running `ssh -t bash -i` as this will skip your `.profile`.